# Powershell won't output folder path?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When I filter some folders and output to a html file, the path in the result is always empty.
I can't find why it only works on files but folders?

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source -Filter *PML_*_ECR* | where { $_.psiscontainer } | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)} | sort LastWriteTime -descending | select name,LastWriteTime,Directory | convertto-html -head $a -body "<H2>Folder LIST FOR PAST 7 DAYS </H2>" | out-file $output\results.htm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders are represented as [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects, which don't have a `Directory` property. The full path of the folder object itself is provided via the `FullName` property:

```
... | select Name, LastWriteTime, FullName | ...
```

The path of the parent folder can be obtained via the `Parent` property:

```
... | select Name, LastWriteTime, @{n='Directory';e={$_.Parent.FullName}} | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `Directory` is not a property of that object. Try doing:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source -Filter *PML_*_ECR* | where { $_.psiscontainer } ||GM
```

Then look at the available properties. I think FullName may better suite your needs.